# Getting a list of installed extensions and packages in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Is there a simple way to get a list of installed extensions and packages in Visual Studio 2013?

I would like to capture what is installed so that I can do a remove and reinstall and get things back to the same as  before the reinstall.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can get a list of installed extensions and packages from the Help - About Microsoft Visual Studio dialog. The Copy Info button copies this list as text to the clipboard.

Comment: wow, that was simple! sadly the url or extension-id is not included.

Comment: Works in VS 2017. Thank you!

Comment: Also there is no information if the extension is disabled (for debugging purposes of extensions)

Comment: For anyone here running the latest VSC, this doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 7):

Google brought me here so I figured I'd update this for 2019.

I wanted a way to copy my extensions for VS2017 to VS2019. While the above method does indeed give you a list the method outlined [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/use-your-favorite-extensions-with-visual-studio-2019/) by the legendary Mads Kristensen is the way to go.

TLDR; [Download Extension Manager 2017 for VS2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ExtensionManager). [Download Extension Manager 2019 for VS2019](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ExtensionManager2019). Export from 2017 and import to 2019.

---

[Extension Manager 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ExtensionManager2022)